# Как бэкапить приложение Android через скрипт?

Tags: android, bash, резервное-копирование, мобильные-приложения

Как бэкапить приложение целиком (т е не только apk, но и содержимое `/data/data/com.author.appname` и `/data/user_de/0/com.author.appname`) в Android? Бэкапить желаю строго с консоли shell-скриптом.

Использовать `adb` не желаю, скрипт должен быть локальным.

Использовать `bu` или `bmgr` тоже нежелательно. `bu` вообще вызывает диалог о резервном копировании, хотя я хочу просто и "тихо" получить архив с бэкапом, как это делает Titanium Backup.

Проблема бэкапа в том, что я не могу просто так взять и сделать `tar -cJ --with-selinux -f /sdcard/backup.tar.xz`, т к при перестановке приложения у него поменяется UID, так что как быть - я хз. Чёрт бы с SELinux - `restorecon` тут в случае чего точно поможет, но меня волнует проблема UID и возможной корректной работоспособности приложения после восстановления с такого бэкапа.

ОС - Android 10.

Comment: у tar есть параметры  `--owner=ИМЯ` и `--group=ИМЯ`  которые так же должны помочь в решение проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, ответ все же нашёл:

1.У `rsync` есть опциии *-o*, *-g*, но самое главное - *chown=UID:GID*. Делаем так:

```
 ~ # rsync -r /data/data/com.author.appname/* /data/backup
```

Это только backup. Восстановление делаем так:

```
 ~ # export NEWUID=$(ls /data/data -l | grep com.author.appname | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
 ~ # rm -rf /data/data/com.author.appname/*
 ~ # rsync -ogr --chown=$NEWUID:$NEWUID /data/backup/* /data/data/com.author.appname
```